# How do i make the tabs touch the top of the screen in chrome on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser-tabs

Currently my tabs default to ~10 pixels under the top of the screen, even though chrome itself  is touching the very top. trying to drag it up causes it to snap back or maximize.

Comment: Why not turn of Area Snap? And consider adding a nice screenshot just for good measure!

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done. The browser has to be maximized for that.

Answer (score 1):

Can not be done without editing the chrome source :). The little space is there for the reason of being able to pull the window around.

Comment: Unfortunately, you’re right, it cannot even be done by using a different theme. There was a discussion about this on the Chrome issue tracker, but I can’t find it right now.